# How to test the value of ensure in a custom type?

Tags: puppet

I've been writing custom types for Puppet, and I've run into a case where for both 'latest' and 'present' I require the existence of certain parameters, but for 'absent' I would like those parameters to be optional.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to test the value of 'ensure' within the ruby code.

```
Puppet::Type.type(:fubar) do
  ensurable do
    desc 'Has three states: absent, present, and latest.'
    newvalue(:absent) do
      # ...
    end

    newvalue(:latest) do
      # ...
    end

    newvalue(:present) do
      # ...
    end

    def insync?(is)
      # ...
    end

    defaultto :latest
  end

  # ...

  validate do
    # This if condition doesn't work.  The error is still raised.
    if :ensure != :absent
      unless value(:myprop)
        raise ArgumentError, "Property 'myprop' is required."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So, my question is simple... How do I test the value of 'ensure' so that when it is 'absent', the validation is NOT performed?

Comment: Are you asking how to write an RSpec test for this? Also, you can combine those conditionals as `unless :ensure == :absent || value(:myprop)`, and you should probably be doing a `nil` check on the `myprop` value and not a truthiness check.

Comment: Not an rspec test.  The if condition doesn't work.  Even when ensure is absent, the error is still raised.

Comment: Added comment to that effect.

Comment: Oh so you want to know how to fix your code. Ok, I can help with that. Edit: I started writing up an answer but then got "in the weeds" explaining stuff since you can do code in types and providers with several different class methods which have unclear differences in functionality. I recommend looking at something like this to see how to fix your code (pay close attention to accessing property existence, values, and provider triggering): https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file.rb#L364-L395

Comment: `if :ensure != :absent` looks wrong to me.  You are comparing the *symbol* `:ensure` to the symbol `:absent`.  That will always evaluate to `false`.  Surely you want instead to compare the value of the `ensure` *property* of the current resource to the `:absent` symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both Matt Schuchard and John Bollinger for their help.

The problem is that:

```
if :ensure != :absent
```

is indeed comparing two symbols, where I need to be comparing the value of a property to a symbol:

```
if self[:ensure] != :absent
```

I am sufficiently new to both Puppet and Ruby that I didn't realize the difference.  John stated it clearly, and Matt provided a good example.

Again, Thanks to both Matt and John.